# Как подписать Label на событие класса?

Tags: c#, события, формы

Пишу приложение, для которого надо выводить информацию из объекта созданного мною класса в Label.Text. Создал тестовый проект: форма, на ней Label1 и Button1. (Visual Studio 2019 - Windows Forms App - Net Framework). За основу взял [статью "События C# по-человечески"](https://habr.com/ru/post/213809/). Хочу запустить счетчик по нажатию на Button1 и вывести значение счетчика в Label1.Text с помощью события. Код генерации события студия одобрила. А вот как написать обработчик события, который выводит в Label1.Text значение счетчика, и как подписать его на событие onCount() - даже не могу представить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать? Или хотя бы правильное направление поисков.

Код тестового проекта:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp_NetFrameWork_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ClassCounter MyCounter = new ClassCounter();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyCounter.onCount += ???

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyCounter.Count();
    }


    class ClassCounter
    {
        public delegate void MethodContainer(int k);

        public event MethodContainer onCount;

        public void Count()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (i == 71)
                {
                    onCount(i);
                }
            }
        }    
    }

    class ??? Как-то так представляю себе обработчик события onCount
    {
        public void ChangeMyLabel(int i)
        {
            this.Text = "Подсчитано: " + i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...
MyCounter.onCount += onCountHandler;
...
private void onCountHandler("то, что вы хотите передать, например int i")
{
     Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
}
```

Вы подписываете на событие метод, которые совпадает по сигнатуре с вызывающем событие.
Ключевые слова для поиска: события и их обработка C#, делегаты

Обращение к методу(например onCountHandler) на самом деле в полной форме выглядит как this.onCountHandler, просто this опускается для элегантности.
Вот как на самом деле в полной форме выглядит ваш кусок кода.

```
public Form1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.MyCounter.onCount += this.onCountHandler;
}
```

Поэтому если вы вынесите метод вне класса, то если у вас не будет конкретного экземпляра в области видимости, вы и не сможете к обратится к функции. Смотрите

```
class Человек
{

  public void Зайти()
  {
      СказатьПривет();
      // Эквивалент this.СказатьПривет();
      // Надо записаться в журнале, что я пришел
      Писать();
      // Напомню, что эквивалент this.Писать(); Но вы же не объявляли в рамках данного класса такого метода, поэтому и вызвать не можете. 
      // Ошибка, непонятно у кого вызывать этот метод. У меня такого метода нет, а ссылка на того, кто может это сделать нет. Исправляем
      Ручка ТекущаяРучка = new Ручка();
      ТекущаяРучка.Писать();
      //Вы создали экзмепляр класса и вызвали метод писать у этого экземпляра. Теперь все верно.
      // О логике я не думал в примере, очевидно ручка сами не пишет, ей пишет человек. Но суть должны быть понятна.
  }
  public void Уйти()
  {
      ...
  }
  public void СказатьПривет()
  {
      Зайти();
      // Эквивалент this.Зайти();
  }
  public void СказатьПока()
  {
      ...
  }

}
class Ручка
{
   public void Писать()
   {

   }

 }
```

Как узнать, кому принадлежит метод, а кому нет? По скобочками. Это называется областью видимости. Все, что внутри скобочек класса - принадлежит классу и видно только внутри класса(доступно по ключевому слову this), остальное находится вне класса.

Почитайте про "область видимости" внимательнее(прям загуглите),например тут https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.18.php

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
В C# я новичок, и, простите, но Ваш ответ напрямую никак не помог. При попытке писать этот код выскакивают сообщения вроде "имя не существует в текущем контексте". И так со всеми советами в интернете! Можно сказать, случайно я перенес onCountHandler в другую часть кода - и вдруг все заработало! Что мне надо знать, чтобы не путаться в том, что остальные, похоже, даже не замечают???
Еще раз - спасибо за ответ, он работает!

Comment: @Дмитрий в данном случае нужно смотреть про область видимости и вообще понятие класса и объекта. 
Вызывать функции/свойста т.е обращаться к элементам класса вы можете только при прямом обращении к нему.

Если вы хотите обратится к Label1 и вы явно его вызываете.
Если вы хотите вызвать функцию внутри текущего класса, вы пишите просто название метода. Но на самом деле вы тоже обращаетесь через имя. В данном случае через ключевое слово this(переводится как "этот"Ю т.е класс, которому я принадлежу). Например this.onCountHandler. Просто слово this опускается для элегантности.

Comment: Ваш кусок кода на самом деле выглядит так(смотрите ответ)

Comment: О! Большое спасибо!
Ссылку на Метанит сейчас почитаю.
Параллельно я пытаюсь запустить свое исходное приложение. И там студия с областью видимости вроде соглашается. Но в отладке при попытке записи в label_Rx_Addr.Text (аналог Label1.Text) выскакивает Сообщение=Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'label_Rx_Addr' не из того потока, в котором он был создан. 
Пока зацепился за фразу "BeginInvoke поставит код на выполнение в тот поток, в котором был создан label1 и продолжит выполнение фонового потока." (Работа с контролами из фонового потока:SO).

Comment: @Дмитрий тут уже сложнее. Если вкратце, то весь поток UI - происходит в одном неизменном потоке и данные могут изменятся только в нем. Тобишь UI можно менять только в том потоке, в котором крутится UI. Вам нужно переключится на тот поток. Для этого нужно с Dispatcher потока UI разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Arantler! Заработало. К сожалению, таким, как я, новичкам подобные ответы мало чем помогают. Кроме того, ЧТО кодить, надо понимать еще ГДЕ. Для таких, как я, выкладываю заработавший код.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp_NetFrameWork_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ClassCounter MyCounter = new ClassCounter();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyCounter.onCount += onCountHandler;
        }
    }

    public void onCountHandler(int i)
    {
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyCounter.Count();
    }


    class ClassCounter
    {
        public delegate void MethodContainer(int k);
        public event MethodContainer onCount;

        public void Count()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (i == 71)
                {
                    onCount(i);
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```